# How to change a class of a menu item in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a layout with a menu navigation.  I'm using a template I found online.  There is an HTML page for each menu item and the li item class is called "selected" for each corresponding page.  It looks like this:

```
  <nav>
    <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
      <li class="selected"><%= link_to "home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "about me", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "my portfolio" %>
        <ul style="z-index: 2;">
          <li style="z-index: 2;"><%= link_to "portfolio one", portfolio_one_path %></li>
          <li style="z-index: 2;"><%= link_to "portfolio two", portfolio_two_path %></li>
          <li style="z-index: 2;"><%= link_to "portfolio three", portfolio_three_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><%= link_to "blog", blog_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "contact", contact_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

So this is in my `application.html.erb` file.  My question is how do I programmatically change each li item's class to "selected" depending on which link the user clicks on?  Can this be done with Ruby or do I need to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `current_page?` helper method - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

```
<li class="<%= "selected" if current_page?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to "home", root_path %></li>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like:

```
<%= link_to "portfolio one", portfolio_one_path,  class: current_page?(products_path) ? "selected" : "not_selected" %>
```

for your links

Answer (score 0):

The controller and action names are available to your views in the params hash. So, if these are different actions/controllers, you can do something like below:

```
<li class=<%= "selected" if params[:controller] == 'portfolio' && params[:action] == 'action_name' %>><%= link_to "portfolio one", portfolio_one_path %></li>
```

**I'm personally not a big fan of this approach and keeping this in my views directly. Usually, I push logic into my helpers and use those.**