# Can you chang the HTML class of a nav link with ruby

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to change the `class="active"` selector on an HTML element using embedded Ruby?
This would be for the `nav` menu for the application.

I was unable to find any question related to this.  If this has already been answered please point me there.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Application", root_path %></li>            
    <li><%= link_to "Posts", posts_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
```

I would obviously like the "active" class to change to to reflect the current page.

I can do with `JQuery` but i am learning and would like to use Ruby only, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to add active class to the link according to the page displayed? If so then, here is a basic idea for that.

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'controller1' %>"> <a href="/link">Link</a> </li>
 <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'controller2' %>"> <a href="/link">Link</a> </li>
 <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'controller3' %>"> <a href="/link">Link</a> </li>        
</ul>
```

Comment: I substituted 'controller1' etc for my controllers but the active class doesn't seem to change.  I get no errors.

Comment: @Dominofoe I had the same concept but using controllers instead of paths. However I see you already found your answer, as they used the current_page helper. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Link To Related Question With Correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656577/how-to-change-a-class-of-a-menu-item-in-rails?rq=1)

After loading this page for the tenth time, i got a list of related questions to pop up on the right.

The **first** answer to the linked question is the answer i was looking for.

Please up vote his answer for me since i do not have enough rep to do yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass current tab as a parameter to link_to method and compare the tab value while adding css active class.
Here is the some basic idea,

```
  <%= link_to "Posts", posts_path(:tab => 'post') %> ----> same for remaining options

  <ul class="nav">
     <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'post' %>">  <%= link_to "Posts", posts_path(:tab => 'post') %> </li>
     <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'tab2' %>">  <%= link_to "Tab2", posts_path(:tab => 'tab2') %></li>     
  </ul>
```

Note - You can add meaning full name to tabs and compare according.